# xs:any wrapper xml schema validation

Tags: xml, xsd

Hi I'm trying to find a way to develop a schema that extends another schema validate XML structures.
Lets say we have Schema A and it contains an extension point using the `<xs:any>` element
So that we have a schema like this:

**Source.xsd**:

```
<xs:complexType name="AType">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="B"/>
      <xs:any/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="A" type="AType"/>
```

Can I make another schema that will validate this XML with a reference to the original schema?

**Extended.xml**:

```
<A>
  <B></B>
  <C></C>
</A>
```

I would like to create a schema that will validate the whole `A` (with the `C`) element without me having to rewrite the whole `AType` to incorporate the `C` element. I also can't use the `redefine` element.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First, xs:any has a processContents attribute with values strict, lax, or skip. Strict means "validate the content; if you can't find a schema definition for the content treat it as invalid". Lax means "if you can find a schema definition for the content, then use it to validate the element". Skip means don't validate.

Sometimes this will be enough.

If you want more control, then you can validate parts of a document independently under application control. For example, you can do this readily using schema-aware XSLT or XQuery. In XSLT, for example, you can navigate to an element you want to validate and then use xsl:copy-of select="x" validation="strict" to validate the subtree rooted at that element.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Just to delve into it abit more on the "any" construct. From what I understand, what gets validated is the 'new' additional element/content from another schema, is it possible for you to validate the whole 'larger' structure with another schema?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood the question. When you validate an element, that implies validating the subtree rooted at that element.

Comment: This was exactly the clue that I needed. Thank you! I had a "parent" XSD with 'processContents' set to 'skip' and I couldn't figure out why I couldn't get my inner schema to validate (even though I was passing the inner schema to the validator). Setting this to "strict" or "lax" enabled validation of my 'xs:any' segment. Again, huge thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way using current 1.0 specs (Michael's requires XSLT 2.0 and up) would be for you to use the head of a substitution group instead of the xs:any wildcard. Version 1.0 would give you wider interoperability vis-a-vis availability of the software stack.

Unlike xs:any, with substitution groups you need to anchor it with a base type. I recommend to make it a complex type. It can be an empty complexType definition, so that it doesn't carry any "excess" baggage.

Validation would then simply be to point the parser to the schema containing the members of the substitution group instead of the base one.

UPDATE: adding sample XSD to illustrate; yours updated as SubstitutionGroupExample.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="AType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="B"/>
            <xs:element ref="any" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="A" type="AType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="TAny" abstract="true"/>
    <xs:element name="any" type="TAny" abstract="true"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Extended.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/1" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:base="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" schemaLocation="SubstitutionGroupExample.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="someAny" substitutionGroup="base:any">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="base:TAny">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="new"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

A valid XML (based on Extended.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:ext="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/1">
    <B>anyType</B>
    <ext:someAny>
        <ext:new/>
    </ext:someAny>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>What I think Petru is suggesting</s> - and something we actually use - is this: you define

**Base.xsd**

```
<xs:complexType name="AType"> 
  <xs:complexContent> 
    <xs:sequence> 
      <xs:element name="B" type="BType"/> 
      <xs:group ref="ATypeExtra"/> 
    </xs:sequence> 
  </xs:complexContent> 
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:element name="A" type="AType"/>
```

**Simple.xsd**

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="Base.xsd"/>

<xs:group name="ATypeExtra">
  <xs:sequence>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

**Extended.xsd**

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="Base.xsd"/>

<xs:group name="ATypeExtra">
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="C" type="CType"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

and then use either **Simple.xsd** or **Extended.xsd** for the validation depending on which definition you want.

In our case we have a system with a core schema that must not change but can be extended in different installations, so we distribute the equivalent of **Base.xsd** above with all the `xxxExtra` groups (and attribute groups) references, that are then defined in different ways in each installation.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my post to include an example of what I meant with substitutionGroups. What you added is something that's also correct. There's also a pattern referred to as "dangling" in that references to external XSDs are not explicitly coded through schemaLocation, but left to be resolved contextually by the schema loader.

Comment: I like the dangling type, its a best practice for creating variable contents! What I'm aiming for is that I don't touch the base/source.xsd. Thanks for your input!