# Webservice dynamic data transport and validation

Tags: java, web-services, validation, endpoint

A webservice should validate input data and write to the database. Later, other services should read the data and create a xml file from it.

So the service just does data transport and transformation (WS-* Parameter => Database).

The "dynamic" webservice should also contain a variable set of parameters ("container"), cause the client changes a lot and quickly which should not end in modification of the interface and the underlying implementation.

**How to do and where to handle the validation?**

Initial Ideas:

- Just send a file as attachment and validate it in the webservices with a .xsd schema for the "fixed" and a .xsd schema for the "container" part. If the variable part changes only the "container" .xsd for validation has to change. The container can be base64 encoded xml. If a validation error occurs, the webservice responds with an error.
- Use all standard items as WSD parameters and pass a base64 encoded container. WS-* takes the validation for the standard parameters and only the container is validated against another .xsd.

No logical/semantic evaluation of the values, that should be done later. Only field-type validation needed.

The container should be xml like:

```
 ... standard elements xml ...
 <embeddedContainer>
  <customItemsFromWSClientOne>
   <reallyCustomItemA>
    <substructure>
     <itemABC></itemABC>
   </substructure>
   <anotherStructure></anotherStructure>
   </reallyCustomItemA>
 </customItemsFromWSClientOne>
</embeddedContainer>
... standard elements xml ...
```

Another Client may send other parameters like 'customItemsFromWSClientTwo' with a complete different structure. So the service will become very generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main types of validations:

1. field type validation - make sure that the values sent are of the correct type and formation (i.e. check that the field userName contains a string, or id contains a number etc.), this is taken care of by the webservice parser/FW. So if the user sent the wrong type the parser would throw an error.
2. Logical validation - run some business logic on the actual values:

   if(value==null){//do something}
   else{//do something else}

I'm not sure what validation you need, but from what i understand, the "container" should be very dynamic, so it'll probably contain something like:

```
<paramName>someParamName</paramName>
<paramValue>someValue</paramValue>
 ...
```

In that case an XSD validation won't do you much good, you probably need to write some logic to figure it out.

I might be completley wrong about the structure, if so please post some example so i can understand it better.

**EDIT:**

In order to enable the "container" to contain all kinds of XML structure, you'll need to define it as [xsd:any](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp). you can define the `processContents` attribute to `strict` and if the right namespace is defined the webservice parser should be able to validate it. look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_any.asp) for more info.

Another option might be using groups, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528634/xsany-wrapper-xml-schema-validation).